# How do I animate an element only if it has not been interacted with?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, delay

I want to create a popout that is visible when the page loads but if the user does not interact with it, it will slide off screen after a set amount of time.

This would be using jQuery and I have found an example but been unable to recreate it.

Here is the example site: http://www.greatwolf.com/

You can see their "Book Your Stay" popout will close after a few seconds if it has not been interacted with.  but if you select a date within the popout it will not close.

I know how to make something animate after a delayed time of course.

```
 $('.side-res-widget-trigger').delay(3000).animate({
        left: parseInt($('.side-res-widget-trigger').css('left'),10) == 0 ?
            -$('.side-res-widget-trigger').outerWidth() :
            0
    });
    $('.side-res-widget').delay(3000).animate({
        left: parseInt($('.side-res-widget').css('left'),10) == 0 ?
            -$('.side-res-widget').outerWidth() :
            0
    });
```

But unsure how to only trigger this if nothing has been interacted with inside the popout.

Comment: By interact, do you mean click?

Comment: Basically,  I mean say there was datepickers, spinners and a text input, if the user is entering information or choosing dates I don't want it to slide off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `setTimeout()` event, and a control variable to see if is "interacted". If not, `setTimeout` will run normally. Something like:

```
var interacted = false;

$('#myPopup').on("click", function() {
    interacted = true;
});

setTimeout(function() {
    if(!interacted) {
        //Hide process
    }
}, 3000);
```

Where `'#myPopup'` is your popup element, any interaction would trigger the `click` event.

Comment: Would this register the click if the user was interacting with any child elements like datepickers, spinners, or text field?

Comment: @Fogolicious. Yes it would. See a simple example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mejm63vt/